# Drawing graphics in Java

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I am trying to draw a circle in side a square and having multiple square circles in java. I am almost done but my output isn't coming out as I wanted to. The picture is what I am trying to do but it's not working out.

[image: This is what I am trying to draw[1]]
Here is my code:

```
a.awt.*;

public class SquaredCircles {
    public static final int WIDTH=400;
    public static final int HEIGHT=400;

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
        Graphics g = panel.getGraphics ();

        panel.setBackground(new Color(0, 255, 255 ) );

        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        int size = 100;
        int rows = 5;
        int numSquares = 1;

        drawManySquares ( g, numSquares, x, y, size, rows );

        x = 10;
        y = 120;
        size = 24;
        rows = 4;
        numSquares = 4;

        drawManySquares( g, numSquares, x, y, size, rows );

        x = 150;
        y = 20;
        size = 40;
        rows = 6;
        numSquares = 5;

        drawManySquares( g, numSquares, x, y, size, rows );

        x = 130;
        y = 275;
        size = 36;
        rows = 3;
        numSquares = 3;

        drawManySquares( g, numSquares, x, y, size, rows );
    }

    public static void drawManySquares( Graphics g, int numSquares, int x, int y, int size, int rows ) {
        for ( int i = 0; i < numSquares; i++ ) {
            for ( int j = 0; j < numSquares; j++ ) {
                drawOneSquare( g, x + i  size, y + j  size, size, rows );
            }
        }
    }

    public static void drawOneSquare( Graphics g, int x, int y, int size, int rows ) {
        g.setColor ( Color.GREEN);
        g.fillRect(x , y, size, size);

        g.setColor ( Color.YELLOW);
        g.fillOval ( x, y, size, size);

        g.setColor ( Color.BLACK);
        g.drawLine(size / 2, x, size / 2, size);
        g.setColor ( Color.BLACK);
        g.drawLine(x, size / 2, size, size / 2);

        for (int i = 0; i <= rows; i = i + 1) {
            g.setColor ( Color.BLACK);
            g.drawOval(x + (i* (size/rows)), y+ (i*(size/rows)), size - (i*(size/rows +10   )) , size - (i*(size/rows +10)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: panel.getGraphics isn't how custom painting is done in Swing/AWT. Create a custom component extending from something like JPanel and override the paintComponent method (and call super.paintComponent before you do any custom painting)

Comment: use console debugging

Comment: It won't hurt and will fix a swagger of other potential issues.  See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details.  Change your logic, you're not so much drawing a square and circles as you are drawing circles which happen to be in a square

Comment: A simple step at a time, can easily sort thingies out for you. Just write the logic to draw top left circle with rectangle, inside a method. Now you simply have to use a for loop and iterate over it, given number of times to draw the rest of the pictures. This one is not a tough question... Please just try once, you need to just define logic for one thingy, and rest will only have different values, nothing more :-)

Answer (score 3):

Start by having a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) to see how painting should be done in Swing

Break down your problem into manageable chunks.  The first thing you need to be able to do is paint a circle of a given size at a specific location, something like

[image: Circle]

```
public void paintCircleAt(Graphics2D g2d, int radius, int centerX, int centerY, Color stroke, Color fill) {
    Ellipse2D.Double circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(centerX - radius, centerY - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2);
    g2d.setColor(fill);
    g2d.fill(circle);
    g2d.setColor(stroke);
    g2d.draw(circle);
}
```

So, this allows you to paint a circle of a given radius around the center points of x/y filled and outlined with the specified color, pretty simple.

Now, you need someway to paint a series of circles around the same center point, something like...

[image: Cirlces]

```
public void paintCirclesIn(Graphics2D g2d, int count, int radius, int centerX, int centerY, Color stroke, Color fill) {

    System.out.println(radius + "; " + centerX + "; " + centerY);

    int delta = radius / count;
    int innerRadius = radius;
    for (int index = 0; index < count; index++, innerRadius -= delta) {
        paintCircleAt(g2d, innerRadius, centerX, centerY, stroke, fill);
    }

}
```

Okay, this basically calculates the difference (delta) between each circle and the paints that many circles with that much difference in their radius from the previous one.  Because of the way the painting is done, we start with the outer circle and paint in.

And finally, we need someway to paint a square and circles, something like...

[image: Square]

```
public void paintCirclesInSquare(Graphics2D g2d, int count, int x, int y, int width, int height, Color squareStroke, Color squareFill, Color circleStroke, Color circleFill) {
    int centerX = x + (width / 2);
    int centerY = y + (height / 2);
    int radius = Math.min(centerX, centerY);
    Rectangle2D box = new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, width, height);
    g2d.setColor(squareFill);
    g2d.fill(box);
    g2d.setColor(squareStroke);
    g2d.draw(box);

    paintCirclesIn(g2d, count, radius, centerX, centerY, circleStroke, circleFill);

    g2d.drawLine(centerX, y, centerX, y + height);
    g2d.drawLine(x, centerY, x + width, centerY);
}
```

This, again, simply reuses the existing code we already have and adds to it, painting the square, the circles in the square and finally the lines.

Now, from here, you could write a method which took the number of columns/rows you wanted, the x/y position to start from, the size of each of square, the number of circles you need and the colors and reuse this functionality, but I'll leave that up to you ;)

Runnable example for you to play with...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class CirclesAndSquares {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CirclesAndSquares();
    }

    public CirclesAndSquares() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);
            int x = getWidth() / 2;
            int y = getHeight() / 2;
//          paintCircleAt(g2d, Math.min(x, y), y, y, Color.BLACK, Color.YELLOW);
//          paintCirclesIn(g2d, 5, Math.min(x, y), x, y, Color.BLACK, Color.YELLOW);
            paintCirclesInSquare(g2d, 5, 0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1, Color.BLACK, Color.GREEN, Color.BLACK, Color.YELLOW);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

        public void paintCirclesInSquare(Graphics2D g2d, int count, int x, int y, int width, int height, Color squareStroke, Color squareFill, Color circleStroke, Color circleFill) {
            int centerX = x + (width / 2);
            int centerY = y + (height / 2);
            int radius = Math.min(centerX, centerY);
            Rectangle2D box = new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, width, height);
            g2d.setColor(squareFill);
            g2d.fill(box);
            g2d.setColor(squareStroke);
            g2d.draw(box);

            paintCirclesIn(g2d, count, radius, centerX, centerY, circleStroke, circleFill);

            g2d.drawLine(centerX, y, centerX, y + height);
            g2d.drawLine(x, centerY, x + width, centerY);
        }

        public void paintCirclesIn(Graphics2D g2d, int count, int radius, int centerX, int centerY, Color stroke, Color fill) {

            System.out.println(radius + "; " + centerX + "; " + centerY);

            int delta = radius / count;
            int innerRadius = radius;
            for (int index = 0; index < count; index++, innerRadius -= delta) {
                paintCircleAt(g2d, innerRadius, centerX, centerY, stroke, fill);
            }

        }

        public void paintCircleAt(Graphics2D g2d, int radius, int centerX, int centerY, Color stroke, Color fill) {
            Ellipse2D.Double circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(centerX - radius, centerY - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2);
            g2d.setColor(fill);
            g2d.fill(circle);
            g2d.setColor(stroke);
            g2d.draw(circle);
        }

    }

}
```